# How to update field in database from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, controller, updates

I have a user who must complete a field without to be logged in. The field is a email_field. 
The database have two field : user email and a user_id the user_id is received it from a webhook so I need to update the field in my database after receiving the information from the webhook.

Here is my controller to insert data in my user email in my database :

```
class EmailsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def new
    @email = Email.new
  end

  def create
    @email = Email.create(email_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if@email.persisted?
        format.html {redirect_to invoice_index_path, notice: 'Email created '}
      else
        format.html{render :new}
      end
    end
  end

  private 

  def email_params
    params.require(:email).permit(:email, :id_user)
  end
end
```

My controller from where I receive the webhook :

```
class InvoiceController < ApplicationController
def webhooks
    render status: 200

    user = Email.last
    #id_user that I need to fill in my database
    puts user.user_id.inspect
    #id_user receive from the webhook
    id_user = params.dig('connection', 'id_user')

    if user.user_id == nil
        #POST the id_user in my database
    end       
end
```

Here is my question, how can I update the file from user.user_id with the id_user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the correct answer is :

```
user.update_attribute :user_id, params.dig('connection', 'id_user')
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line before your `if` statement should work, it will update and automatically save the updated record.

```
user.update_attribute(user_id, id_user)
```